# Not able to call the function...I don't understand why the function isn't being called, what am I missing?

Tags: c, struct

In this fragment of a program, I am trying to call cases_wise function but despite me calling it in the main function, this function isn't being called, So, can any one spot where I am creating an error? Thank you

```
 struct country{
    char country_name[30];
    int active_cases;
    int recovered_cases;
    int dead_cases;
    };

void cases_wise(struct country count[], int n );

int main(){

    int i, n;
    printf("***********WELCOME***********\n");
    printf("Enter the number of countries: \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    struct country count[10];
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        printf("Enter the name ");
        scanf("%s", &count[i].country_name);

        printf("Enter the number of active cases ");
        scanf("%d", &count[i].active_cases);

        printf("Enter the number of recovered cases ");
        scanf("%d", &count[i].recovered_cases);

        printf("Enter the number of dead cases ");
        scanf("%d", &count[i].dead_cases);

    }

    cases_wise(struct country count[], int n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `cases_wise(struct country count[], int n);` is not how you call a function. Please re-read your instruction/book/lecture notes on how a function call looks like in C

Answer (score 2):

In your main:

```
cases_wise(struct country count[], int n);
```

is a *prototype*. It is not a call. To call the function, remove the type names:

```
cases_wise(count, n);
```

Comment: when I do that, It throws an error saying: error: expected ')' before 'int', how do I resolve this?

Comment: Thank You very much, sir. Yes, I am revising the function chapter.

Answer (score 0):

first problem is as the answer of Paul Ogilvie in your code. Your program has other things to improve:

```
scanf("%s", &count[i].country_name);
```

Do not use the `&` for string, and add `%29s` to avoid overflow:

```
scanf("%29s", count[i].country_name);
```

Your for loop need another condition of `i`: `i < 10`, because the size of array `count` is 10.

```
for(i=0; i<n && i < 10; i++){
  // your code
}
```

Comment: The `i<n && i < 10` condition is odd, I'd check if `n` is >= 10 beforehand.

Comment: @Jabberwocky yes, he can do it before, but check `n > 10` not `>= 10`. He can create a loop until `n <= 10` or throw an error when `n > 10`.

Comment: Hey, yes you're right, I was aware beforehand that size of count is 10.